# Requesting Kibana Data using REST

Tags: rest, kibana

I have access to a Kibana Server at some domain, let's call it mykibana.com. Some data is being uploaded to this server, and I want to programatically request this data from Kibana using REST. For example:

https://mykibana.com/kibana/api/data/_search

with an additional JSON request body such as:

```
{
  "query" :
    "match" : {
       "title" : "bla"
    }
}
```

Theres's plenty online about using the API within the Console through the Kibana Web UI but this is not what I need. I'd be really appreciate any help people can give!

Many thanks,
Peter

Comment: You doing search REST request on elasticsearch server not on kibana server

Comment: I'm pretty new to Kibana but I expect that's the case. I can only find elasticsearch examples to use within the console for Kibana.

Comment: The data is in elasticsearch, kibana is the tool that visualize the data. What you trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to be able to perform a GET request with CURL to get the raw data from elasticsearch, I do not want to visualise it using Kibana at all. I will process the data using another application and wish to request it programmatically.

Comment: Which programming language you using?

Comment: I was probably going to use NodeJS, but I guess the request is going to be the same regardless.

Comment: So use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html

Comment: Ah thanks! Am I right in assuming that there is no way to just perform (for the time being) a simple get request through a browser or curl to get the raw JSON response? Do I have to perform everything through some kind of elasticsearch client?

Comment: You can do that, in kibana do to console developer, there you can perform elastic request , or is Sense plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html

Comment: Ahhh OK. If I were to make a request then, I can just swap out localhost in the uri to the remote server address instead? E.G mykibana.com/_search... Thanks very much for your help!